# How to retrieve _id from ListView Position

Tags: android

I need to retrieve the _id of an item in Listview. All I can get now is the position. How can I do that?. This is the code I'm using.

```
public class OSListActivity extends ListActivity { 
................
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
................
................
        MatrixCursor cursor;
        cursor = datasource.getnameList();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            startManagingCursor(cursor);
            String vdstatus = cursor.getString(6);
            System.out.println("vdstatus : " + vdstatus);
            String[] from = { "name", "desc", "status", "path", "folder",
                    BaseColumns._ID };
            int[] to = { R.id.name, R.id.desc, R.id.status, R.id.path };
            final VSsimplecursoradapter adapter = new VSsimplecursoradapter(
                    this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, VSDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("com.manager.boot.r1223."+BaseColumns._ID, position);//TODO put _id instead of position
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Edit: Solution**

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // Starts TestDetails activity on clicking a list item.
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, VSDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("com.manager.boot.r1223."+BaseColumns._ID, cursor.getInt(cursor
            .getColumnIndex("_id")));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: What on earth is _id? You need to elaborate.

Comment: @straya it is a string `BaseColumns._ID` the adapter uses as column name.

Comment: Good example of why it pays to not be ambiguous when asking a question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already got it.  Look at the parameters for the method.  See the "Long id" part?  That's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I use `String s = ((Cursor) l.getItemAtPosition(position)).getString(0);` and just parse it to a long.